# What's a good repo to fork if you want to create a blockchain like a "Math" coin or Curecoin. (mining equations, not hashes)

Tags: hash, hashpower, proof-of-work, proof-of-stake

I want to create my own crypto currency and I want to know what's the best github repo to fork when it comes to making a blockchain that's based off of getting the miners to do mathematical calculations. I understand that a lot of coins just require miners to guess hash values. I want my miners to do something more, just like cure coin and folding coin do. 
Are there different security principles for these coins?